# java MonetaryConversions throws ArithmeticException for high digit currencies

Tags: java, currency, arithmeticexception, java-money

I'd like to use standard java MonetaryConversions to convert currencies.

At first glance it works very well and simple:

```
    @Test
    public void testConversion()
    {
        FastMoney usd = FastMoney.of(1000, Monetary.getCurrency("USD"));
        usd.with(MonetaryConversions.getConversion("EUR"));
    }
```

However I find that is throws ArithmeticExceptions, when I use currencies that have high nominal values like japanese yen or Mexican Pesos

```
    @Test
    public void testArithmeticException()
    {
        FastMoney jpy = FastMoney.of(1000, Monetary.getCurrency("JPY"));
        jpy.with(MonetaryConversions.getConversion("EUR"));
    }
```

throws following exception

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: 0.0082769 can not be represented by this class, scale > 5

    at org.javamoney.moneta.FastMoney.getInternalNumber(FastMoney.java:197)
    at org.javamoney.moneta.FastMoney.multiply(FastMoney.java:388)
    at org.javamoney.moneta.FastMoney.multiply(FastMoney.java:84)
    at org.javamoney.moneta.spi.AbstractCurrencyConversion.apply(AbstractCurrencyConversion.java:118)
    at org.javamoney.moneta.FastMoney.with(FastMoney.java:594)
    at tech....GatewayTransactionConverterTest.testArithmeticException(GatewayTransactionConverterTest.java:207)
```

Checking the code of FastMoney I see that the exception is quite hardcoded and I cant find anything where I could reduce e.g. the scale.

But with this the conversion offered by java out of the box is quite useless as I cannot convert for really a lot of currencies. I cannot imagine that nobody has this issue. But I can't find anything with google.

Comment: Can you use the bigdecimal-based Money class?The FastMoney class is based on longs, which you shouldn't rely on for high precision currency calculations.

Comment: that's it. Thanks a lot!

Don't know why we use all the time FastMoney ... going to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [dementis mentions in a comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59181879/java-monetaryconversions-throws-arithmeticexception-for-high-digit-currencies/62314983#comment104584883_59181879)

> Can you use the bigdecimal-based Money class?The FastMoney class is based on longs, which you shouldn't rely on for high precision currency calculations.

this worked for me.